# select(.key="value") emits even non-matching items

Tags: jq

I have the following test.json

```
{"type":"RECORD","record":{"key_A": "apples","key_B":"bananas"}}
{"type":"RECORD","record":{"key_A": "apples","key_B":"oranges"}}
```

Then see the following command and output.

```
cat test.json | jq 'select(.record.key_B="oranges")' 
{
  "type": "RECORD",
  "record": {
    "key_A": "apples",
    "key_B": "bananas"
  }
}
{
  "type": "RECORD",
  "record": {
    "key_A": "apples",
    "key_B": "oranges"
  }
}
```

I wish it would only output the record which match the select - the ones where .record.key_B = oranges so only the first record. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: ...given which, this seems like a "close as typo" candidate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is an assignment operator. `==` is an equality-comparison operator.

You want `select(.record.key_B == "oranges")`.